# Reverse the values of a range if falling on the same date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a series of data as shown below

[image]

I need a code in VBA to reverse the values if they fall on the same date.

The new data should appear as

[image]

I have around 40,000 entires, so can't do this manually.

Comment: What version of excel have you got? And can you include your own attempt?

Comment: Is the data in order in any of those other columns (in the example all columns have a perfect order), if so this could be done very easily by filtering the right headers in the right order.

Comment: @JvdV I got how to reverse the data in a range by using this formula =INDEX($B$5:$B$7, ROWS(B7:$B$7)). But the issue is that I need to find the date range

Comment: @jamheadart Test <number> and Test <alphabet> are just arbitary data. The crux is, i want the data reversed across the row and not just single column

Comment: I'm adding an answer to explain this, because Excel preserves preserves the previous column sort order. Even if you DON'T have a perfect order column, you could simply add one to sort it in reverse, then sort on date again. It affects ALL columns on all rows.

Comment: Please check out the answer, you don't need VBA for this, it's simple table sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily if you have an ordered column. If you don't have an ordered column, just add one and fill it with sequence 1-40,000

[image: Original Data]

First sort reverse on your ordered column (column B here):

[image: Sort by ordered column]

Then sort by oldest date again:

[image: Final sorting]

Excel preserves the reverse sorting from the first sorted column (like most good tables!)

No VBA required unless you want to automate adding the ordered column, sorting and removing the helper column again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code, please. Working in memory (using array and dictionary), it should be fast enough. It will return processed range starting from "F1" cell:

```
Sub testSwapValues()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim arr As Variant, arrF As Variant, i As Long, key As Variant
  Dim k As Long, arrKey As Variant, El As Variant, NrRows As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastRow).Value
  ReDim arrF(1 To UBound(arr) + 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'fill the dictionary
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict.aDD key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=1 & ":" & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4)
    Else
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = Replace(dict(arr(i, 1)), Split(dict(arr(i, 1)), ":")(0), _
          CLng(Split(dict(arr(i, 1)), ":")(0)) + 1) & ";" & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4)
    End If
  Next i
  'fill the arrFin array in the desired way:
  k = k + 1
  'Fill column headers
  arrF(k, 1) = sh.Range("A1").Value: arrF(k, 2) = sh.Range("B1").Value
  arrF(k, 3) = sh.Range("C1").Value: arrF(k, 4) = sh.Range("D1").Value
  'Fill the array from dictonary data:
  For Each key In dict.Keys
    NrRows = CLng(Split(dict(key), ":")(0))
    If NrRows = 1 Then
        k = k + 1
        arrF(k, 1) = arr(k - 1, 1): arrF(k, 2) = arr(k - 1, 2)
        arrF(k, 3) = arr(k - 1, 3): arrF(k, 4) = arr(k - 1, 4)
    Else
        arrKey = Split(Right(dict(key), Len(dict(key)) - Len(Split(dict(key), ":")(0)) - 1), ";")
        For i = NrRows To 1 Step -1
            k = k + 1: arrF(k, 1) = arr(k - 1, 1): arrF(k, 2) = arr(k - 1, 2)
            arrF(k, 3) = Split(arrKey(i - 1), "|")(0): arrF(k, 4) = Split(arrKey(i - 1), "|")(1)
        Next i
    End If
  Next
  
  'drop the array data at once:
  sh.Range("F1").Resize(UBound(arrF, 1), UBound(arrF, 2)).Value = arrF
End Sub
```

The code can be simplified a little, in order to return only the swapped columns, but I thought that it maybe will be needed to copy it in another location (sheet, workbook etc.)...

Comment: @Insight Academy Private Tutori: Should I understand that the code is useful, but it did not answer your question?